# issues routing express routes

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am getting an error indicating.

*Cannot GET /todoListItem*

Not sure why I am getting this error because after researching and reading documentation my routes as shown bellow look correctly defined.

```
       //@route GET to do list page route
        router.get('/showToDoList', function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/todoListItem');
        });

  module.exports = router;
```

in my server.js I am implemting my app use in this manner.

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var todoListItemRouter = require('./routes/todoListItem')

//Bodyparser MiddleWare
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Add to do list routes to middleware chain.
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/showToDoList', todoListItemRouter);
```

in my todoListItem.js I am calling my controller.

```
//@route GET all do list items from user.
router.get('/todoListItem', todoList_controller.todo_lists)
```

I am not sure why I would getting that error shown above. my file dir is implemented

```
-routes
 -- index.js
 -- todolistItem.js
```

in my server.js file I am doing the routing logic. Any help to understand my issue will greatly be appreciated. this is my github repo for more info
https://github.com/OlooAllaN/ToDoList-Project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot GET that file because there is no route defined for /showToDoList.

`app.use('/showToDoList', todoListItemRouter);` tells Express to point all requests matching "/showToDoList" to this router. Any routes defined in todoListItemRouter are accessed by using "/showToDoList/route1", "/showToDoList/route2", "/showToDoList/showToDoList".

The correct way to do this, is to edit your route inside your todoListItemRouter to this:

```
//@route GET all do list items from user.
router.get('/', todoList_controller.todo_lists)
```

This will accomplish the affect that you are looking for. Please see [Express Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) for more information about using external routing files.